# Testing environment for mobile devices, specifically media queries

Tags: iphone, mobile, media-queries

I'm trying to 'mobilize' a site I'm working on using media queries in CSS.

I have an Android phone myself so have been testing on that with good results.

I now want to test on the iPhone but don't have a device, having searched the net and downloaded a few recommended simulators it seems they don't recognise the media queries, but without a device to test on I can;t e sure if my queries don't work - or if its the emulator that doesn't recognise them.

Does anyone know of a emulator for iPhone / iPad that runs on Windows and recognises media queries?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [ProtoFluid](http://app.protofluid.com/) - it's a web app that allows you to emulate an array of mobile devices and tablets, fully recognising media queries.

It's free to use (for now at least).